# How does the compiler/program deduces the size of memory to be deleted(released) in case of delete[] arr;

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

When using `operator new`  we explicitly provide the size of memory to be allocated:

```
int* arr = new int[100];
```

But when deleting, we just type `delete []arr;`
How does the compiler/program calculates the size of arr, as we provide no information about it to `operator delete?`

Comment: It is implementation defined. Frequently, `allocate` function stores the allocated amount just prior to the pointed data.

Comment: The memory manager keeps notes.